# Player Movement Relative to Camera Direction C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I am fairly new to making games in unity and I am trying to get my player to move in a direction relative to the camera position. I have no idea how to do this, below is my code, would someone be able to help me with this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update


    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Transform cam;

    public float movementSpeed = 6.0f;      //speed the player moves at
    public float jumpHeight = 200.0f;       //height of the jump
    public float timeBetweenJumps = 1.0f;   //delay between each jump so the player can't jump again before reaching the ground
    private float timestamp;

    public Vector3 movement;
 
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    void Update()
    {
      
        movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));     
        transform.LookAt(transform.position + new Vector3(movement.x, 0f, movement.z));         // makes the player always face in the direction of movement

        if (Time.time >= timestamp && (Input.GetKeyDown("space")))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.up * jumpHeight;                       // multiplies the players Y position by the jumpHeight variable which causes the player to jump in-game
            timestamp = Time.time + timeBetweenJumps;

        }

    }
    

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveCharacter(movement);    

    }

    void moveCharacter(Vector3 direction)
    {
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (direction * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime));     //moves the rigidbody (player) 
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
// multiplies the players Y position by the jumpHeight variable which causes the player to jump in-game
```

No it does not! What you are doing is completely replacing the velocity so any forward velocity is overwritten by that. Is this intended? If not it should probably rather be

```
if (Time.time >= timestamp && (Input.GetKeyDown("space")))
{
    var velocity = rb.velocity;
    velocity.y = jumpHeight;
    rb.velocity = velocity;                      
    timestamp = Time.time + timeBetweenJumps;
 }
```

Then you are moving in worldspace.

In order to take the camera's orientation into account do e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;

private void Awake ()
{
    if(!mainCamera) mainCamera = Camera.main;   
}
```

And then

```
movement = mainCamera.transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + mainCamera.transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
```

So the input now is used relative to the Camera's current rotation. Note though that this might behave strange if the camera is somehow rotated in other axis than only Y ...